# Can I use Blender like After Effects or Nuke for motion graphics?

Tags: 3d-view, tracking, compositing-nodes

*I was wondering if there's a way to use Blender's 3d Space (not the compositor!) similar to After Effects without adding additional lights to do 3d motion graphics.*

I'd like to use the motion tracker to solve a camera from a video and add some flat titles coming to the camera. If I add lights, the appearance of the texture changes. In After Effects, as well as in Photoshop, there are no lights to be added and they both give a flat even look to all the items you import (photos, vectors, video clips). How can I get the same evenly lit effect in Blender?

In this video you can see the effect I'm trying to achieve: 
https://youtu.be/kFLuiik8RC8?t=469

The guy tracks the chat to the camera but he doesn't need to add lights in AE to make the chat appear. Can I do the that by using Blender as well?

Comment: Sure. Blender is a 3d tool and has all options you need (and more), see josh's answer. However, if time plays a role, it's probably not the fastest way in the world creating any type of motion graphics. AE has exactly that purpose for many years so to get up to that speed you probably have to do some scripting setting up the project settings, type, boxes etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the world strenght down to zero, delete all lights, set the color management as standard (sRGB), and use an emission shader set to 1 strenght instead of a principled BSDF.

[image]